# import javascript file into json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, import, var

Is there any way to import js file into json file.
I have js file config.js

```
module.exports = {id : 'test'}
```

and I want to use the id key into my json file config.json

```
const {id } = require('./config.js')
{user_id : id}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something I have seen be done before, in fact I'm not sure if it is actually possible to actually import `js` file into a `json` file.

However, I would recommend you convert your `json` file to a `js` file instead and then you can have something like:

```
const { id } = require('./config.js');

const data = {user_id : id};

export default data;
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that I can do achieve the goal by converting json into js file. When initializing sequelize using sequelize-cli we get a config.json file. anyhow this will needs to be pushed which is not secure. SO I wanted to know is there any way to import js file into js. else I will convert the json to js as my last option.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to be honest.